# Find the node that has no children. If it has any <span> children, just ignore it

Tags: c#, .net, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTMLAgilityPack. I have something like this:

```
<div class="address">
  <h3>Postadress</h3>
  <div class="box-address">Box  27 </div>
  <div class="post-address">
    16493 KISTA 
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is there are other `<div class="address">`s.
So I have to find the one that has a `<h3>` child with the text "Postaddress".
What I need to extract is the value of `<div class="post-address">` that is "16493 KISTA".
There are other records returned for `<div class="post-address">` that have  children and I don't want those to be returned. I'm only looking for `<div class="post-address">` that has no children and only contains naked text.

My solution so far is:

```
var postAddressdiv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='address']");
if (postAddressdiv != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in postAddressdiv)
    {
        HtmlNode postAddress;
        var h3 = node.Descendants("h3");
        if (h3 != null)
        {
            if (h3.First().LastChild.InnerHtml == "Postadress")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("right place you are.");
                postAddress = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='post-address']");
                var postAddressChildren = postAddress.Descendants();
                if (postAddressChildren == null)
                    MessageBox.Show("found one!!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: why is it "not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nodes  = doc.DocumentNode
            .SelectNodes("//div[@class='address' and h3='Postadress']/div[@class='post-address']");
```